# Placing label within the line of a path diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

I've created a path diagram and I'm trying to put the gamma labels inside the line itself but with little success.

At most, this is what I have achieved so far:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes,arrows} 
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[auto,node distance=.5cm,
latent/.style={circle,draw,very thick,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=30mm,align=center},
manifest/.style={rectangle,draw,very thick,inner sep=0pt,minimum width=45mm,minimum height=10mm},
paths/.style={->, >=stealth'},
]

\node [manifest] (B1) at (0,0) {Business Licencing};
\node [manifest] (C1) [below=of B1] {Courts};
\node [manifest] (C2) [below=of C1] {Crime};
\node [manifest] (C3) [below=of C2] {Customs Regulation};
\node [manifest] (E1) [below=of C3] {Electricity};
\node [manifest] (F1) [below=of E1] {Finance};
\node [manifest] (I1) [below=of F1] {Informal Economy};
\node [manifest] (L1) [below=of I1] {Labour Education};
\node [manifest] (L2) [below=of L1] {Labour Regulation};
\node [manifest] (L3) [below=of L2] {Land};
\node [manifest] (P1) [below=of L3] {Political Instability};
\node [manifest] (T1) [below=of P1] {Tax Administration};
\node [manifest] (T2) [below=of T1] {Tax Rates};
\node [manifest] (T3) [below=of T2] {Transportation};

\node [latent] (l) [left=7.5cm of L1] {$\tilde{\theta_i}$};


\draw[paths] (l.east) -- node {$\gamma_1$} (B1.west);
\draw[paths] (l.east) -- node {$\gamma_2$} (C1.west);
\draw[paths] (l.east) -- node {$\gamma_3$} (C2.west);
\draw[paths] (l.east) -- node {$\gamma_4$} (C3.west);
\draw[paths] (l.east) -- node {$\gamma_5$} (E1.west);
\draw[paths] (l.east) -- node {$\gamma_6$} (F1.west);
\draw[paths] (l.east) -- node {$\gamma_7$} (I1.west);
\draw[paths] (l.east) -- node {$\gamma_8$} (L1.west);
\draw[paths] (l.east) -- node {$\gamma_9$} (L2.west);
\draw[paths] (l.east) -- node {$\gamma_{10}$} (L3.west);
\draw[paths] (l.east) -- node {$\gamma_{11}$} (P1.west);
\draw[paths] (l.east) -- node {$\gamma_{12}$} (T1.west);
\draw[paths] (l.east) -- node {$\gamma_{13}$} (T2.west);
\draw[paths] (l.east) -- node {$\gamma_{14}$} (T3.west);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This is the corresponding output:

[image]

Can anyone advise as to how I can get these gamma labels to be placed midline, within each path arrow?

Comment: Please make your code snippet compilable ...

Comment: Use `\draw[paths] (l.east) -- node[midway,anchor=center,fill=white] {$\gamma_1$} (B1.west);`. Or `\draw[paths] (l.east) -- node[pos=0.5,anchor=center,fill=white] {$\gamma_{14}$} (T3.west);`

Comment: @Bobyandbob That worked perfectly! If you add this as an answer, I'd happily accept.

Comment: @DavidPatrick, now you can choose between four answers :)

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1852/how-do-you-accept-an-answer)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part [of this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, it looks more friendly, if the lines would meet in the center of the circular node, not at the point `l.east` on the circle. In the following example, the lines starts in `l.center`, but clipping prevents them to show inside the circle:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes,arrows}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  auto,
  node distance=.5cm,
  latent/.style={
    circle,
    draw,
    very thick,
    inner sep=0pt,
    minimum size=30mm,
    align=center,
  },
  manifest/.style={
    rectangle,
    draw,
    very thick,
    inner sep=0pt,
    minimum width=45mm,
    minimum height=10mm,
  },
  paths/.style={
    ->,
    >=stealth',
  },
]

\node [manifest] (B1) at (0,0) {Business Licencing};
\node [manifest] (C1) [below=of B1] {Courts};
\node [manifest] (C2) [below=of C1] {Crime};
\node [manifest] (C3) [below=of C2] {Customs Regulation};
\node [manifest] (E1) [below=of C3] {Electricity};
\node [manifest] (F1) [below=of E1] {Finance};
\node [manifest] (I1) [below=of F1] {Informal Economy};
\node [manifest] (L1) [below=of I1] {Labour Education};
\node [manifest] (L2) [below=of L1] {Labour Regulation};
\node [manifest] (L3) [below=of L2] {Land};
\node [manifest] (P1) [below=of L3] {Political Instability};
\node [manifest] (T1) [below=of P1] {Tax Administration};
\node [manifest] (T2) [below=of T1] {Tax Rates};
\node [manifest] (T3) [below=of T2] {Transportation};

\node [latent] (l) [left=7.5cm of L1] {$\tilde{\theta_i}$};

\begin{scope}
  \clip
    (current bounding box.south west) rectangle
    (current bounding box.north east)
    (l) circle[radius=15mm]
  ;
  \def\x#1#2{
    \path
      (l.center)
      -- node[
        anchor=center,
        circle,
        pos=.55,
      ] (tmp) {$\gamma_{#1}$}
      (#2.west)
    ;
    \draw[paths] (l) -- (tmp) -- (#2.west);
  }
  \x{1}{B1}
  \x{2}{C1}
  \x{3}{C2}
  \x{4}{C3}
  \x{5}{E1}
  \x{6}{F1}
  \x{7}{I1}
  \x{8}{L1}
  \x{9}{L2}
  \x{10}{L3}
  \x{11}{P1}
  \x{12}{T1}
  \x{13}{T2}
  \x{14}{T3}
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Answer (score 1):

You have `auto` in the `tikzpicture` settings. The purpose of that setting is that nodes are placed next to a line, not on it. So by removing that, and adding `every node/.style={fill=white}` to the `paths` style, you get this:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes,arrows} 
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  node distance=.5cm,
  latent/.style={circle,draw,very thick,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=30mm,align=center},
  manifest/.style={rectangle,draw,very thick,inner sep=0pt,minimum width=45mm,minimum height=10mm},
  paths/.style={->, >=stealth', every node/.style={fill=white}},
]

\node [manifest] (B1) at (0,0) {Business Licencing};
\node [manifest] (C1) [below=of B1] {Courts};
\node [manifest] (C2) [below=of C1] {Crime};
\node [manifest] (C3) [below=of C2] {Customs Regulation};
\node [manifest] (E1) [below=of C3] {Electricity};
\node [manifest] (F1) [below=of E1] {Finance};
\node [manifest] (I1) [below=of F1] {Informal Economy};
\node [manifest] (L1) [below=of I1] {Labour Education};
\node [manifest] (L2) [below=of L1] {Labour Regulation};
\node [manifest] (L3) [below=of L2] {Land};
\node [manifest] (P1) [below=of L3] {Political Instability};
\node [manifest] (T1) [below=of P1] {Tax Administration};
\node [manifest] (T2) [below=of T1] {Tax Rates};
\node [manifest] (T3) [below=of T2] {Transportation};

\node [latent] (l) [left=7.5cm of L1] {$\tilde{\theta_i}$};


\draw[paths] (l.east) -- node {$\gamma_1$} (B1.west);
\draw[paths] (l.east) -- node {$\gamma_2$} (C1.west);
\draw[paths] (l.east) -- node {$\gamma_3$} (C2.west);
\draw[paths] (l.east) -- node {$\gamma_4$} (C3.west);
\draw[paths] (l.east) -- node {$\gamma_5$} (E1.west);
\draw[paths] (l.east) -- node {$\gamma_6$} (F1.west);
\draw[paths] (l.east) -- node {$\gamma_7$} (I1.west);
\draw[paths] (l.east) -- node {$\gamma_8$} (L1.west);
\draw[paths] (l.east) -- node {$\gamma_9$} (L2.west);
\draw[paths] (l.east) -- node {$\gamma_{10}$} (L3.west);
\draw[paths] (l.east) -- node {$\gamma_{11}$} (P1.west);
\draw[paths] (l.east) -- node {$\gamma_{12}$} (T1.west);
\draw[paths] (l.east) -- node {$\gamma_{13}$} (T2.west);
\draw[paths] (l.east) -- node {$\gamma_{14}$} (T3.west);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

## Code shortening

This may or may not be interesting, but your code can be made a lot more compact by using a `chain` and a loop. Here I also reduced the size a bit, so that it actually fits on one `report` page.

```
\documentclass[12pt,border=5mm]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes,arrows,chains} 
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  latent/.style={circle,draw,very thick,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=30mm,align=center},
  manifest/.style={rectangle,draw,very thick,inner sep=0pt,minimum width=45mm,minimum height=8mm,font=\small},
  paths/.style={>=stealth'},
]

\begin{scope}[
   start chain=list going below,
   every node/.style={manifest,on chain},
   node distance=4mm,
   local bounding box=list
]
  \node {Business Licencing};
  \node {Courts};
  \node {Crime};
  \node {Customs Regulation};
  \node {Electricity};
  \node {Finance};
  \node {Informal Economy};
  \node {Labour Education};
  \node {Labour Regulation};
  \node {Land};
  \node {Political Instability};
  \node {Tax Administration};
  \node {Tax Rates};
  \node {Transportation};
\end{scope}

\node [latent] (l) [left=5cm of list] {$\tilde{\theta_i}$};

\foreach \i in {1,...,14}
   \draw [paths] (l.east) --node[font=\scriptsize,fill=white,inner sep=2pt] {$\gamma_{\i}$} (list-\i.west);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could set `anchor=center` and use `midway` or `pos=0.5` for positiong. To fill the background use `fill=color`. The amount of adding space around the label could be set using the option `inner sep`.

- label anchor: `anchor=center`
- label positioning: `midway` or `pos=0.5`, `pos=0.1`, ...
- white baclground: `fill=white`

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,arrows}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[auto,node distance=.5cm,
latent/.style={circle,draw,very thick,inner sep=0.5pt,minimum size=30mm,align=center},
manifest/.style={rectangle,draw,very thick,inner sep=0.5pt,minimum width=45mm,minimum height=10mm},
paths/.style={->, >=stealth'},
]

\node [manifest] (B1) at (0,0) {Business Licencing};
\node [manifest] (C1) [below=of B1] {Courts};
\node [manifest] (C2) [below=of C1] {Crime};
\node [manifest] (C3) [below=of C2] {Customs Regulation};
\node [manifest] (E1) [below=of C3] {Electricity};
\node [manifest] (F1) [below=of E1] {Finance};
\node [manifest] (I1) [below=of F1] {Informal Economy};
\node [manifest] (L1) [below=of I1] {Labour Education};
\node [manifest] (L2) [below=of L1] {Labour Regulation};
\node [manifest] (L3) [below=of L2] {Land};
\node [manifest] (P1) [below=of L3] {Political Instability};
\node [manifest] (T1) [below=of P1] {Tax Administration};
\node [manifest] (T2) [below=of T1] {Tax Rates};
\node [manifest] (T3) [below=of T2] {Transportation};

\node [latent] (l) [left=7.5cm of L1,inner sep=0.5pt] {$\tilde{\theta_i}$};


\draw[paths] (l.east) -- node[midway,anchor=center,fill=white,inner sep=0.5pt] {$\gamma_1$} (B1.west);
\draw[paths] (l.east) -- node[midway,anchor=center,fill=white,inner sep=0.5pt] {$\gamma_2$} (C1.west);
\draw[paths] (l.east) -- node[midway,anchor=center,fill=white,inner sep=0.5pt] {$\gamma_3$} (C2.west);
\draw[paths] (l.east) -- node[midway,anchor=center,fill=white,inner sep=0.5pt] {$\gamma_4$} (C3.west);
\draw[paths] (l.east) -- node[midway,anchor=center,fill=white,inner sep=0.5pt] {$\gamma_5$} (E1.west);
\draw[paths] (l.east) -- node[midway,anchor=center,fill=white,inner sep=0.5pt] {$\gamma_6$} (F1.west);
\draw[paths] (l.east) -- node[midway,anchor=center,fill=white,,,inner sep=0.5pt] {$\gamma_7$} (I1.west);
\draw[paths] (l.east) -- node[midway,anchor=center,fill=white,inner sep=0.5pt] {$\gamma_8$} (L1.west);
\draw[paths] (l.east) -- node[pos=0.1,anchor=center,fill=white,inner sep=0.5pt] {$\gamma_9$} (L2.west);
\draw[paths] (l.east) -- node[pos=1,anchor=center,fill=white,inner sep=0.5pt] {$\gamma_{10}$} (L3.west);
\draw[paths] (l.east) -- node[pos=0.75,anchor=center,fill=white,inner sep=0.5pt] {$\gamma_{11}$} (P1.west);
\draw[paths] (l.east) -- node[pos=0.5,anchor=center,fill=white,inner sep=0.5pt] {$\gamma_{12}$} (T1.west);
\draw[paths] (l.east) -- node[pos=0.25,anchor=center,fill=white,inner sep=0.5pt] {$\gamma_{13}$} (T2.west);
\draw[paths] (l.east) -- node[pos=0,anchor=center,fill=white,inner sep=0.5pt] {$\gamma_{14}$} (T3.west);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: If you follows the hint of @Torbjørn T to remove `auto` you do not need `anchor=center` anymore.

Answer (score 0):

with use of library `chains` and `quotes`, and with naming chain and use this name for automatic nodes naming, for example `A-1`, `A-2`, etc, you can write diagram code as:

```
\documentclass[12pt,border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, chains, positioning, quotes}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  node distance = 3mm and 77mm,
    start chain = A going below,
  latent/.style = {circle, draw, very thick, minimum size=30mm},
manifest/.style = {rectangle, draw, very thick,
                   minimum width=45mm, minimum height=10mm,
                   on chain},
every edge quotes/.style={fill=white, inner sep=2pt, font=\footnotesize},
                   ]
    \begin{scope}[every node/.style={manifest}]
\node  {Business Licencing};        % A-1
\node  {Courts};
\node  {Crime};
\node  {Customs Regulation};
\node  {Electricity};               % A-5
\node  {Finance};
\node  {Informal Economy};
\node  {Labour Education};
\node  {Labour Regulation};
\node  {Land};                      % A-10
\node  {Political Instability};
\node  {Tax Administration};
\node  {Tax Rates};
\node  {Transportation};            % A-14            
    \end{scope}
\node (L) [latent, left=of A-7] {$\tilde{\theta_i}$};
%
\foreach \i in {1,...,14}
    \draw[-Stealth] (L) edge ["$\gamma_{\i}$"] (A-\i.west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]